# Regex Pattern Matching On Strings Not Containing Certain Patterns

Tags: regex

I have strings of the form: `...format=<format_type>...` where legal `format_type`s can be one of

`image/{png,jpeg,tiff}` or `{kmz,kml}`

i want to match on any string with an illegal format type. For example

`foo&bar&format=image/png` and `foo&bar&format=kml&baz`

should not match, but

`foo&bar&format=image/svg` and `foo&bar&format=application/pdf&baz`

should.

I've tried `.*format=(image\/)?.*(?!=(kml|kmz|png|jpeg|tiff)).*` but this doesnt work.

Comment: Are you trying to match only format i.e. image/svg or entire text i.e. foo&bar&format=image/svg?

Comment: @Tom: i want to match the entire string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a PERL interpreter handy, but this seemed to work in Java:

```
^.*format=(?!(?:image/)?(?:kml|kmz|png|jpeg|tiff)).*$
```

Here's the snippet that tests it:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX = 
   Pattern.compile("^.*format=(?!(?:image/)?(?:kml|kmz|png|jpeg|tiff)).*$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String format : Arrays.asList("foo&bar&format=image/png", 
            "foo&bar&format=kml&baz", "foo&bar&format=image/svg", 
            "foo&bar&format=application/pdf&baz")) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", format, 
            REGEX.matcher(format).matches() ? "matches" : "does not match");
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
foo&bar&format=image/png does not match
foo&bar&format=kml&baz does not match
foo&bar&format=image/svg matches
foo&bar&format=application/pdf&baz matches
```

Comment: This one works fine.  Just have to escape the slash after image: `/^.*format=(?!(?:image\/)?(?:kml|kmz|png|jpeg|tiff)).*$/`.

Answer (score 3):

No doubt there's a regex that matches any illegal format, but writing one that matches looks easier. So a quick workaround could be to find any string that doesn't match the legal pattern instead of finding the strings that match the illegal pattern.

So instead of

```
if (str =~ m/ ...illegal pattern... /) { ... }
```

You could use

```
if not (str =~ m/ ...legal pattern... /) { ... }
unless (str =~ m/ ...legal pattern... /) { ... }
```

So you get:

```
if not (str =~ m/^.*format=(image\/(png|jpeg|tiff))|kmz|kml).*$/) { ... }
```

Comment: you could also use the does not match operator `!~` instead of not

Comment: Didn't know that operator existed, learned something new, thanks!